# Hyperledger Fabric 2.3 Dev Environment Setup mkdir: cannot create directory ‘build’: Permission denied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric2.2

I am trying to setup the development environment as described here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/dev-setup/devenv.html.

I am getting an issue at this stage "make basic-checks integration-test-prereqs"

```
All files have SPDX-License-Identifier headers
Building github.com/client9/misspell/cmd/misspell -> misspell
Checking changed go files for spelling errors ...
xargs: misspell: No such file or directory
spell checker passed
Checking for go:generate parent path references
Checking trailing spaces ...
DEP: Checking for dependency issues..
./scripts/check_deps.sh
mktemp: failed to create directory via template ‘check_deps.sh-XXXXX’: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:191: check-deps] Error 1
```

Getting similar error while "make dist-clean all"

```
Building build/bin/orderer
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘build’: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:230: build/bin/orderer] Error 1
```

Comment: On first read, this looks like the user this is running as doesn't have permissions to write to the directory.

Check your in the correct directory - and running as a user thas full permissions for that dir

Comment: The cloned folder has the permission: drwxr-xr-x. What should it be?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is resolved by giving full permissions to the "fabric" directory in the cloned repo directory.

```
sudo chmod 777 -R fabric
```

Comment: that's quite a broad solution and generally not a good idea to grant complete permissions. Though it'll work, would suggest it's worth investigating at a later time which user was being used.

Comment: When I did "chown -R $USER:$USER /path/to/directory" it gave error "Operation not permitted". Maybe sudo chown would have worked.